What can be determined about wind conditions by examining ripples on a body of water?
I am interested in the fractal patterns of ripples and waves, especially on relatively calm bodies of water. Are there empirical or theoretical descriptions of wave speed based on frequency distribution, fractal dimension, etc.?
